# Android : Fatal Exception Main

Tags: android, exception, program-entry-point, fatal-error

Okay so I'm a total beginner at programming and this is my first programming project. What I wanted to do is create a 'Motivational Quotes' app where it would consist of around 10 person with multiple quotes each. Just some simple view-flipping and randomizing array. I was in the process of coding the view-flipping part and then when I tried to run it in the emulator then it gives me the 'the application has stopped unexpectedly'. Logcat shows 'FATAL EXCEPTION Main'. Hope someone can help me in making this run, I'm stuck at a dead end and the due date's closing in fast.

I tried searching around and most asks for src,main.xml and manifest.xml so I'll just post them here:

src:

```
package first.motivationalquotes;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MotivationalQuotesActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button next,previous;
ViewFlipper vf;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        previous.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    }

    public void randomize(View v)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        String[] ButtonText = null;
        Resources res = getResources();
        ButtonText = res.getStringArray(R.array.Quotes);
        String strRandom = ButtonText[ran.nextInt(ButtonText.length)];
        System.out.println("Random string is : "+strRandom);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText(ButtonText[ran.nextInt(ButtonText.length)]);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == next) {
            vf.showNext();
        }
        if (v == previous) {
            vf.showPrevious();
        }
    }

}
```

Next is the main.xml (only coded to 2 person as of now):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- View 1- Einstein - person1 -->
         <TableLayout 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Albert Einstein"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28dp" >
        </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/clear_einstein" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/einstein1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

         <!-- View 2- Tesla - person2 -->
     <TableLayout 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nikola Tesla"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28dp" >
        </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nikola_tesla" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/einstein1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

     <TableLayout 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Albert Einstein"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28dp" >
        </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/clear_einstein" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/einstein1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    </ViewFlipper>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="button2Click"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="&lt;Previous"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutMeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="randomize"
        android:text="Randomize" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="button1Click"
        android:text="Next&gt;" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

then the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="first.motivationalquotes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MotivationalQuotesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:
http://i56.photobucket.com/albums/g183/luq_man/Logcat.png

Comment: Please post your Logcat content as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must implement OnClickListener.

public MotivationalQuotesActivity extend Activity implements OnClickListener{

...... 
}

Comment: Sorry for being late but the program crashed again when clicking 'next' or 'previous' after moving into another view.

Comment: 05-31 04:35:32.013: E/AndroidRuntime(424): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method button1Click(View) in the activity class first.motivationalquotes.MotivationalQuotesActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

Answer (score 0):

Probably forget to implement `OnClickListener`?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Or something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
Button next, previous;
ViewFlipper vf;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    next.setOnClickListener(nextOnClick);//<--------new listener
    previous.setOnClickListener(previousOnClick);//<--------new listener
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
}

private View.OnClickListener nextOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        vf.showNext();
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener previousOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        vf.showPrevious();
    }
};
```

Comment: private View.OnClickListener nextOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        vf.showNext();
    }
}

-Eclipse is reading the '@Override' as an error.

Comment: Okay I changed the compliance level to 1.6, but I'm getting and unexpected error when clicking 'next' or 'previous' after changing the view from the initial view.

Comment: 05-31 04:35:32.013: E/AndroidRuntime(424): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method button1Click(View) in the activity class first.motivationalquotes.MotivationalQuotesActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

Comment: you must use own name of button, it was just an example, the same with implementing OnClickListener dude, try think..

Comment: It's ok, I got it a few minutes after I posted it, sorry for the late update.